# Is it ok to create a Stripe Payment Intent on the client side?

Tags: stripe-payments

In [the official Stripe documentation about Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents) it shows how to create a client secet on the server side and pass it to the client side? Is there anything wrong with using this api directly on the client side?

Comment: It is not. You should never expose your secret key to th client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not create a Payment Intent on the client side. It is dangerous because it is impossible to create a PaymentIntent without a [secret key](https://stripe.com/docs/keys), and you definitely do not want to expose your secret key publicly. If someone gets a hold of your secret key they can control your Stripe account entirely; create charges, transfer funds, the works.

Comment: Sorry It is a bit misleading. becauae the title says "is it ok....". I understandf why you said yes because the small print asks the question in a different way. I am going t edit your answer before I accept.

Answer (score 0):

We will not expose 'server secret key' to create a Payment Intent at client side. We expose only 'public key' & 'client secret'.